# Django: Querying many-to-one model instance fields

Tags: django, model, key

I've been playing around in the Django tutorial and am trying to get the field of a model instance associated (via foreign key) to another model instance. Here is what I mean:

Model file:

```
from django.db import models

class Usercar(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.DateTimeField('year of car')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.make

class Suggestcar(models.Model):
    usercar = models.ForeignKey(Usercar)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.DateTimeField('year of car')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.make
```

In the shell, this is what I get when I try to get the make of a suggestcar related to a usercar:

```
>>from django.utils import timezone
>>mycar1 = Usercar(make="Ford",model="Escort",year=timezone.now())
>>mycar1.save()
>>mycar1.suggestcar_set.create(make="Ford", model="Taurus", year=timezone.now())
>>mycar1.suggestcar_set.filter(id=1).make
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 mycar1.suggestcar_set.filter(id=1).make

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'make'
```

How can I get the make of this mycar1.suggestcar_set.filter(id=1)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns a queryset, if you want to access the objects in it, you need to iterate over the queryset or get the first result from it.

```
mycar1.suggestcar_set.filter(id=1)[0].make
```

If you want to return just 1 object, you should really use [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get)

```
mycar1.suggestcar_set.get(id=1).make
```

Comment: This is still returning a DoesNotExist error for me...I'll let you know if I'm messing up somewhere and it works. Thanks!

Comment: What is causing that error? `DoesNotExist` and `AttributeError` are very different. If you are getting `DoesNotExist` then there aren't any results for the provided query. You can try `mycar1.suggestcar_set.values()` to see all of the `Suggestcar` objects related to `mycar1`